# Is token functionality required to be implemented when I have only facebook and google login

Tags: node.js, rest

I am making a web & mobile app. In app, I don't have custom login. But I have only facebook & google login. APIs ate written in node.js . Should I use jsonwebtoken or is it ok not to have that token system, as I don't have any custom signup/login?   In this app we have also guest user functionality.

Comment: Using JWT is a way to ensure that differents request are done by authorized users. If you dont need that just dont use it. Login through facebook does not ensure that is a real user, it just ler you know that it is a real facebook user.

Comment: I also have guest login,so is it ok with JWT?

Comment: Yes totally, I've built a small mobile app with Node Backenk (restify) using JWT and I had not any problems.

Comment: Yes, I totally get your point. When user is guest user(means no login), should they use JWT?

Comment: No, I think if there is no login you dont need JWT then. Probably if the user does not login it will only access to public information.